# How to run a program in WSL when I click on an executable?

Tags: c, exe

Imagine I have a simple program that prints out hello, world to the terminal when executed.

Usually, you would type in the terminal ./a.out or whatever the name and extension (or not) of the program.

I want to create an executable file that, when clicked, will open the terminal and run the program. I'm using windows and linux subsystem for windows and the debian terminal from the windows store. How can I make my program open the debian terminal and run the hello world program, when I click on the executable?

Comment: A debian terminal emulator like [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) can be started running a specific program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create **.bat** file with startup of your app via wsl:

```
wsl NEEDED_DIR/a.out
```

Comment: The needed dir would be a dir in the WSL file system, so that should be `wsl sh -c "cd NEEDED_DIR; ./a.out"`. Of course, one could simply use `wsl NEEDED_DIR/a.out` instead of changing the directory.